# Print line containing pattern preceded by different line containing a different pattern

Tags: regex, macos

macOS 13.3 Ventura hence BSD versions of grep, awk, et al.

How do I search for and print a line containing a pattern where the line MUST be preceded by a different line containing a different pattern?

The text contains lines like these (leading CAPS for reference, ...==irrelevant chars).

```
  ...                   # An indeterminate number of lines.
A ... "model" = \< ...
  ...                   # An indeterminate number of lines.
B ... PXS4@0 ...
  ...                   # An indeterminate number of lines.
C ... "model" = \< ...
  ...                   # An indeterminate number of lines.
D ... PXS2@0 ...
  ...                   # An indeterminate number of lines.
E ... "model" = \< ...
  ...                   # An indeterminate number of lines.
F ... PXS1@0 ...
  ...                   # An indeterminate number of lines.
G ... "model" = \< ...
  ...                   # An indeterminate number of lines.
H ... "model" = \< ...
  ...                   # An indeterminate number of lines.
```

ONLY lines with "model" that are preceded by a line with PXS[[:digit:]]@0 should appear:

```
C ... "model" = \< ...
E ... "model" = \< ...
G ... "model" = \< ...
```

AFAICT the regex in macOS's awk & grep do not support look-behind and look-ahead.

I thought this would find a match of PXS... and then find/print model... but it prints line "A":

```
awk '/(PXS\[\[:digit:\]\]@0 )+?model" = \</ { print }'
```

This also comes close but prints line "A". Since it prints "A" I don't understand why it doesn't also print "H".

```
grep -e ".\*PXS\[\[:digit:\]\]@0 " -e ".\*model" = \<"" | grep -v -e ".\*PXS\[\[:digit:\]\]@0 "
```

Enlighten me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for steering me in the right direction. This gives me lines C, E, and G.

I used a loop in awk to find the first line with `PXS[[:digit:]]@0` and a sub loop to find the second with `"model" = <`. The file is deterministic: if the first line is present, the second will be (but not directly after the first).

I also set awk's delimiters since the final value I want is after `"model" = \<"` and before `">`.

```
awk -F'<"|">' 'BEGIN {while (getline != 0) if ($0 ~ /PXS[[:digit:]]@0 /) {while (getline != 0) if ($0 ~ /"model" = </){print $2; break;}}}'
```

I like having the whole thing in one awk command, my other solution required 5 piped greps.

Answer (score 0):

###### MacOs

```bash
perl -n0e 'print $_ =~ /PXS[[:digit:]]@0.*\n.*\n/g' filename | perl -p -e 's/PXS[[:digit:]]@0[^\n]*\n//g'
```

First step: leave only lines with `PXS[[:digit:]]@0` and the next lines.
Second step: remove lines with `PXS[[:digit:]]@0`

###### Linux

```bash
grep -zoP 'PXS[[:digit:]]@0.*\n.*\n' filename | sed -z -E 's/PXS[[:digit:]]@0[^\n]*\n//g'
```

Grep to find lines with `PXS[[:digit:]]@0` and the next lines, sed to remove lines containing `PXS[[:digit:]]@0` from output.

Comment: Thanks, but macOS's grep doesn't have the -P flag and sed doesn't have -z. I tried removing those but it only printed  the "B", "D", and "F" type lines. Also, the "model" lines can be separated from the others by an indeterminate number of lines.

Comment: @SamuelHerschbein, sorry, wasn't aware of differences in sed and grep in macos. Do you have perl (you can type `perl --version` to check) and is it acceptable to use it in this case?

Comment: Perl is 5.30.3, I can use Perl.

Comment: @SamuelHerschbein, added perl solution

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
awk '/PXS[0-9][@]0/{getline;if(match($0,"model")){ print;}}'
```

`/PXS[0-9][@]0/` will match the prefix line

`getline;` will read the next line (and populate $0)

`match($0,"model")` will see if that line contains the regexp 'model'

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work because the line after /PXS[0-9][@]0/ is not the line with "model". There is an indeterminate number of lines between the two. I'll dust off my awk (OK, search the web...) to put the getline in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/model/ && match(prevline,/PXS[0-9]@0/){print} {prevline=$0}' file
C ... "model" = \< ...
E ... "model" = \< ...
G ... "model" = \< ...
```

Comment: Thanks but this won't work. The two lines are not sequential, they can be separated by an indeterminate number of lines.